# Can you disable drush pm-update for a site?

Tags: drush

Can you disable `drush pm-update` for a particular site in drushrc.php?

I have a server which houses the DEV and LIVE versions of the site.  Work is done directly on the DEV site.  Changes to the LIVE site are deployed via `git pull` from a shared remote on the same filesystem.

In an effort to prevent **Doing Something Stupid™**, and running a `pm-update` and `pm-updatecode` on the LIVE site, I would like to disable these commands for that site.

The `$command_specific[]` syntax allows you to specify persistent options for commands (like `--no-core`), but I would like to fully disable `pm-update` and `pm-updatecode` for this particular site.

Is this possible?

Comment: This won't help with the question, but I'm curious...how are you running db updates if not through drush? Are you pushing the db upstream too?

Comment: @Clive Basic procedure is go into maint. mode, git pull, drush updatedb, drush cc all, spot check, go out of maint mode.

Comment: Doh, ignore me I read that wrong. Thought you weren't running `updatedb` on live

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the core Update module on the live site,  and then should prevent being able run pm-update on live:

> $ drush pm-disable update
>  The following extensions will be
>   disabled: update
>  Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
>   update was disabled successfully. [ok]
>  $ drush pm-update
>   Command pm-update needs the following modules installed/enabled to
>   run: update. [error]
>  The drush command 'pm-update' could not be
>   executed. [error]

Comment: Not sure why I dind't think about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement [drush_hook_pre_COMMAND](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!drush!docs!drush.api.php/function/drush_hook_pre_COMMAND/7) which says

> Run before a specific command executes. Logging an error stops command
>   execution.
>
> Logging an error stops command execution, and the rollback function
>   (if any) for each hook implementation is invoked, in addition to the
>   validate rollback.

By implementing above hook in custom module and throwing an error should disable command.

As said in above answer Disabling module will be best option in above case..  But , I believe above hook will be handy if only drush command need to be disabled instead of module itself.. Most of the cases module disable may not be good option since it's functionality may be required to run drupal.. For example to disable user-add-role command we cannot disable user module.

One more way is to configure in drush configuration file as explained [here](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.drushrc.php)

```
/**
 * Specify the modules to ignore when searching for command files (*.drush.inc)
 * inside a Drupal site.
 */
# $options['ignored-modules'] = array('module1', 'module2');
```